# Assign 100 percent unevenly between a variable number of items

Tags: calculus

I have a variable number of web sites to which I wish to redirect traffic. I'd like to assign a bigger chance to the first one on the list than the second, and so on.

For example:

Site 1: 100%

---

Site 1: 60%
Site 2: 40%

---

Site 1: 55%
Site 2: 35%
Site 3: 15%

Ideally, the percentage change ratio between site 1 and site 2 should be the same as the change ratio between site 2 and site 3.

Is there a formula to achieve this?

Comment: There are probably many ways to do it. Do you have any more specifics of how the traffic should be distributed? Maybe you mean site 3 on the third spot of the third case.

Comment: for example:  choose $n-1$ random numbers from $0$ to $100$ and let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be the $n$ gaps formed.  The gaps add to $100$ and you can sort them in whatever order you like.

Comment: Hello @mathreadler and thank you for answering. I don't have any specific requirements on how the traffic should be distributed as long as: a) The sum of all sites is 100%. b) The percentage decrements linearly from site to site. I'm sorry if I can't explain it better, my math knowledge is very basic (to say the least).
PS: You're right about the third case, it was a typo.

Comment: What do you mean by "decrements linearly"?  Note:  the method I sketched randomizes the assignments...I can see reasons to dislike it (for large $n$ you will probably have some clustering in the random numbers you pick, hence many gaps near $0$).

Comment: Sorry @lulu. I mean that the percentage change ratio between site 1 and site 2 should be the same as the change ratio between site 2 and site 3.

Comment: Oh, that should be added into the question then.  It makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: I see the edit but you should be aware that "percentage change ratio" suggests a multiplicative factor whereas I believe you mean an additive one.  In any case, I have posted a solution to the problem as I understand it.

Comment: Note:  the $3$ site example you gave is incorrect.  $55+35+15=105$.  In my posted solution I give the values I think you intended, assuming an additive drop of $20$ at each stage.

Comment: Thank you @lulu your answer is exactly what I needed. And so well explained even I could understand it. Have a nice day! ;)

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, from the comments, the goal is to fix $d$ and then require that the additive drop between sites $s_i$ and $s_{i+1}$ be $d$.

Assume $d,n$ are fixed.  Then all we need to know is the amount of traffic to the first site, call it $s_1$.  Then $s_i=s_1-(i-1)d$ so we compute $$100=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(s_1-(i-1)d\right)=ns_1-\frac {(n-1)(n)}2d$$

It follows that we should take $$\boxed{s_1=\frac {100}n+\frac {n-1}2d}$$

Example:  $n=3,d=20$.  Then $$s_1=\frac {100}3+20=53.333\dots$$
Thus in this case your numbers should be $\{53.333,33.333,13.333\}$.  Note that the numbers you gave do not add to $100$.

Answer (score 3):

There are infinite many ways. One of the ways is to use geometric sequence. For example, if $n$ denotes the number of sites then you can assign $x$ to site $n$, $2x$ to site $n-1$, $\cdots$, $2^{n-1}x$ to site 1. The sum of the percentages should be 100. Consequently, $x(1+2+\cdots + 2^{n-1})=(2^n-1)x=100$. Therefore, $x=100/(2^n-1)$.

This is just an example. You can generate $n$ percentages randomly and assign the sorted percentages to the sites. You can use arithmetic sequence etc.